# Is it appropriate to use question marks in email?

Tags: politeness, email, question-mark

I am a student and write to professors frequently.
And often, I have to use sentences like this -

> Could you give me an appointment to meet you regarding this matter.

I am usually confused whether to type a question mark at the end of this sentence or a plainly end it with a full stop. Typing a question mark appears a bit rude to me, so I often end the sentence in a full stop.

Comment: How is using a question mark rude?

Comment: I am confused why you think a question mark is a bit rude. How do you usually end your questions?

Comment: I would think without a question mark is more rude, presumptively turning it from a passive aggressive lead on directly to a command.

Comment: I don't know. Now that I have asked the question, I feel like an idiot. This was bugging me for some time, so took time to ask it here. I thought this would be a common feeling, but evidently, it isn't.

Comment: @KitFox: Tsk. And you a *mod* supposed to be helping to make ELU a "welcoming" site. OP already *told* you he finds question marks offensive, and you just throw one right back at him!

Comment: I meant it honestly. Maybe it is a cultural difference; we had a long discussion about some convoluted phrasing in chat the other day that it seems would be polite in India and rude in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a question, you should use a question mark:

> Could you give me an appointment to meet you regarding this matter?

If anything, leaving out a question mark from a question could make it seem rude.

To make it more polite, include *please*:

> Please could you give me an appointment to meet you regarding this matter?

Comment: Okay. This is probably a culture thing. I understand now.

Comment: Perhaps, but you didn't say where you're from (or where your professor is), and I don't know of any cultures where a single question mark makes a question rude (multiple question marks is another matter.)

Comment: However every culture surely has some sort of *please* custom in a polite expression of desire.